# iphone local notifications when application in active

Tags: iphone, notifications

I'm developing a chat application for `iOS` 5. I had a problem with local notifications.
When application went to background state, I am using this code:

```
  UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
  localNotification.alertAction = @"Ok";
  localNotification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"From: %@\n%@",message.sender,message.message];

  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:localNotification];
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
  [localNotification release];
```

but when application is in active state ,and  it is not in chat page then also I need the local notification but I used the same code there also
the notification is coming in tray but banners are not coming....

Please help me out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THe following code handles both remote and local notification

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
    [self showNotificationAlert:notification.alertBody];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    NSString *alertMsg = nil;
    id alert = [[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"alert"];

    if ([alert isKindOfClass:NSString.class])
        alertMsg = alert;
    else if ([alert isKindOfClass:NSDictionary.class])
        alertMsg = [alert objectForKey:@"body"];

    [self showNotificationAlert:alertMsg];
}

- (void)showNotificationAlert:(NSString *)alertMsg
{
    if (!alertMsg)
        return;

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Message", nil)
                                                    message:alertMsg
                                                   delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", nil)
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Following method put into your application Delegate

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification 
{
    UILocalNotification *localNotif =notification;
    NSString *strBody=[localNotif.userInfo valueForKey:@"Body"];
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Your Application name" 
                                                    message:strBody
                                                   delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" 
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];

    //NSLog(@"Incoming notification in running app");

    // Access the payload content
    //NSLog(@"Notification payload: %@", [notification.userInfo objectForKey:@"body"]);

    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
}
```

Comment: the notification is coming as an alert, what i need is should be banner

Comment: in this method when the notification being aries and that time you shows the alert.

may this help to you.