# iOS Push Notification Banner did not appear

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I tried execute the below code in my main class (***ViewDidLoad***) but apparently the banner just did not appear on my phone. I noticed that the notification did pop up at the notification centre. Just that on screen the banner did not appear when the application still remains as active.

```
        UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
            localNotif.alertBody = @"Test Push Notification";
            localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
            localNotif.soundName=@"default";
            [application presentLocalNotificationNow:localNotif];
```

I implemented ***scheduleLocalNotification*** to test as well but the result is the same.
I'm not really sure what's wrong. Any help or comment will be much appreciated.

Comment: It seems like you app is running in the foreground when you schedule the notification, is that the case? If so that's the reason you're not seeing the notification.

Comment: My application is up and running. It is in active state when I trigger the local notification. I'm clueless about what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

You will not see a local notification if your app is in the foreground. From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/WhatAreRemoteNotif.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH102-SW1):

> If your app is frontmost, the
>   `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:` or
>   `application:didReceiveLocalNotification:`method is called on its app
>   delegate

This means that you should implement these methods in your app delegate. Here's an example of how to do so:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
   UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Message", nil)
                                                   message:notification.alertBody
                                                  delegate:self
                                         cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", nil)
                                         otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

(Code adapted from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12527667/2560190))

Comment: The above function works as in it will appear an alertview, but I just wanted the banner to appear when the user using the application.

Comment: @IssacZH. As far as I know it is not possible to show the notification bar when the app is in the foreground. However, you can implement a similar looking bar yourself.

Comment: But my application did not enter foreground. I did not quit my application. All I did was trigger the local notification

Comment: @IssacZH. What do you mean 'did not enter foreground'? If you mean that it was already there then the answer is still the same - no notification bar will be shown if your app is the frontmost app.

Comment: Wait.... I got a bit confused. Correct me if I'm wrong. So according to what you said is that even if my app state is active, notification bar would not appear no matter what?

Comment: @IssacZH. Not EVEN but rather BECAUSE. If your app was running in the background (i.e. was not shown on screen) then you would have seen the banner.

Comment: Oh okay. I got the idea now. Do you have any source that I can do some reading about this? I was hoping not to bother user with an extra alertview instead just display out the "banner" from the notification.

Comment: There are two links in my answer that you can begin with (especially the first one which is from Apple's documentation). Here's [a nice tutorial about local notifications](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-local-notification-tutorial/). Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Add this and check

```
localNotif.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:2];
```

Comment: I added that line of code but it still didn't appear. =(

Comment: have you handled notification after they fire? I mean did you update the codes in appdelegate.m file?

Comment: I only handled for RemoteNotification but not LocalNotification.

Comment: schedule it and handle at didFinishLaunchingWithOptions